# Check if a action is repeated five times in less than a minute (JS)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple game built on javascript , And in order to prevent cheating I want to prevent repeat a specific action more than five times in less than a minute
(java script)

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with? You'probably want to use `setTimeout` here though.

Comment: It will be better If you add some use case if you don't have code to share in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to take care off check the user taking action and his number of actions. User can be checked by user id possibly.

If you will use `settimeout` for every user it will an overhead for you system.
Better store user actions in some storage with time and clear it after one min (don't use settimeout for that instead on every action check last date time and if it is more then 1min clear storage). That way you can keep check of action count and time.

For storage you can use localstorage or cookies for client side.
For server side redis maybe

In case of JS define globle varible or closures along with a counter to keep track of values.

If you need clarification ping me.